# Get Only One Part Of a CSV URL

Tags: javascript, csv, yahoo

If you take a look at Yahoo Finance, you may notice that you can retrieve information from their servers using a URL, that might lead to a CSV file. Let's use as example this URL: `http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=USDBRL=X`, it will return this:

```
"USDBRL=X",1.6294,"3/31/2011","12:06pm"
```

But how I can use that URL to retrieve that information and store only the money value(`1.6294`) part using Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to split the string into an array using `str.split(",")` and take the second element. This is not completely bulletproof (it assumes there are no commas in the first column), but it might be robust enough for a simple script.